# HTTP requests works in eclipse, but fail in compiled JAR package

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using Apache HTTPclient 4 to send a SPARQL query to a remote repository. While program is identical, the response that my JAR package get is HTTP 406, error message is "No acceptable file format found." while in eclipse, my query successful receive HTTP 200 response and the desired result.

What can possibly cause the two environments with the identical code operate differently?

Eclipse Message: (HTTP 200)

```
19:32:23.584 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.h.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager - HttpConnectionManager.getConnection:  config = HostConfiguration[host=http://asimov.ludat.lth.se], timeout = 0
19:32:23.585 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.h.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager - Allocating new connection, hostConfig=HostConfiguration[host=http://asimov.ludat.lth.se]
19:32:23.585 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.httpclient.HttpConnection - Open connection to asimov.ludat.lth.se:80
19:32:23.589 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> "POST /openrdf-sesame/repositories/KnowRob HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
19:32:23.590 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - Adding Host request header
19:32:23.593 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
19:32:23.594 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> "Accept: application/x-binary-rdf-results-table[\r][\n]"
19:32:23.594 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> "Accept: application/sparql-results+xml;q=0.8[\r][\n]"
19:32:23.595 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> "Accept: application/xml;q=0.8[\r][\n]"
19:32:23.596 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> "Accept: text/tab-separated-values;q=0.8[\r][\n]"
19:32:23.596 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> "Accept: text/csv;q=0.8[\r][\n]"
19:32:23.597 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> "User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1[\r][\n]"
19:32:23.597 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> "Host: asimov.ludat.lth.se[\r][\n]"
19:32:23.598 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> "Content-Length: 836[\r][\n]"
19:32:23.598 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> "[\r][\n]"
19:32:23.599 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.content - >> "quer[...]rue"
19:32:23.600 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.h.m.EntityEnclosingMethod - Request body sent
19:32:24.304 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
19:32:24.304 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
19:32:24.305 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"
19:32:24.305 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "Vary: Accept[\r][\n]"
19:32:24.306 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=query-result.brt[\r][\n]"
19:32:24.306 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "Content-Type: application/x-binary-rdf-results-table;charset=ISO-8859-1[\r][\n]"
19:32:24.306 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "Content-Language: en-US[\r][\n]"
19:32:24.307 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
19:32:24.307 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "Date: Thu, 28 Feb 2013 18:28:24 GMT[\r][\n]"
19:32:24.307 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "[\r][\n]"
19:32:24.308 [main] DEBUG org.openrdf.http.client.HTTPClient - reponse MIME type is application/x-binary-rdf-results-table
```

JAR message: (HTTP 406)

```
19:15:35.178 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.h.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager - HttpConnectionManager.getConnection:  config = HostConfiguration[host=http://asimov.ludat.lth.se], timeout = 0
19:15:35.179 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.h.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager - Allocating new connection, hostConfig=HostConfiguration[host=http://asimov.ludat.lth.se]
19:15:35.179 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.httpclient.HttpConnection - Open connection to asimov.ludat.lth.se:80
19:15:35.183 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> "POST /openrdf-sesame/repositories/KnowRob HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
19:15:35.184 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - Adding Host request header
19:15:35.187 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
19:15:35.188 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> "Accept: text/tab-separated-values;q=0.8[\r][\n]"
19:15:35.188 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> "Accept: text/csv;q=0.8[\r][\n]"
19:15:35.189 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> "User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1[\r][\n]"
19:15:35.189 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> "Host: asimov.ludat.lth.se[\r][\n]"
19:15:35.189 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> "Content-Length: 836[\r][\n]"
19:15:35.190 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> "[\r][\n]"
19:15:35.191 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.content - >> "query[...]er=true"
19:15:35.191 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.h.m.EntityEnclosingMethod - Request body sent
19:15:35.717 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable[\r][\n]"
19:15:35.717 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable[\r][\n]"
19:15:35.718 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"
19:15:35.718 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "Vary: Accept[\r][\n]"
19:15:35.718 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
19:15:35.719 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "Content-Language: en-US[\r][\n]"
19:15:35.719 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "Content-Length: 32[\r][\n]"
19:15:35.719 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "Date: Thu, 28 Feb 2013 18:11:35 GMT[\r][\n]"
19:15:35.720 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "[\r][\n]"
19:15:35.720 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - Buffering response body
19:15:35.720 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.content - << "No acceptable file format found."
19:15:35.721 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - Resorting to protocol version default close connection policy
19:15:35.721 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - Should NOT close connection, using HTTP/1.1
19:15:35.721 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.httpclient.HttpConnection - Releasing connection back to connection manager.
19:15:35.721 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.h.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager - Freeing connection, hostConfig=HostConfiguration[host=http://asimov.ludat.lth.se]
19:15:35.722 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.h.util.IdleConnectionHandler - Adding connection at: 1362075335721
19:15:35.722 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.h.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager - Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
19:15:35.722 [main] WARN  org.openrdf.http.client.HTTPClient - Server reports problem: No acceptable file format found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case , your application/environment is sending the header as

```
19:32:23.594 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> 
"Accept: application/x-binary-rdf-results-table[\r][\n]"
```

but this is missing in second case and so your second environment can't accept responses of type `'application/x-binary-rdf-results-table'` . Where are you running your second query ? where is the jar deployed ? You may need to add this encoding/type to your app server.

I am not very clear on where you are using this but the good starting point is to see why `"Accept: application/x-binary-rdf-results-table` is missing in second case.